# How to get the auto-generated ids of the row which is inserted into table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am designing Hotel Booking system, where after insertion of the customer information I have to send back conformation page with the booking_id which is auto-generated when customer information is inserted.

**My Question is How to get the booking id in the same php code after the insertion  of data**

please Note also more that one person is Inserting the data so I think **It can't be achieve by just returning last inserted row**
Please help me on this.

My javascript is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#register-form").validate({
            rules: {
                userName: "required",                           
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },                                              
                userContactNumber: "required"                       
            },
            messages: {
                userName: "Please enter your Name",
                userContactNumber: "Please enter your Mobile number",                           
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",                                           
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {

                var uName = $('#userName').val();   
                var mailId = $('#email').val();                 
                var mobNum = $('#userContactNumber').val();

                $.ajax({                
                    url:"http://localhost/bookRoom/book.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{type:"booking", Name:uName, Email:mailId,  Mob_Num:mobNum},                                   
                    ContentType:"application/json",
                    success: function(response){                            
                        window.location.href = 'BookingConformation.html';
                    },
                    error: function(err){                           
                        window.location.href = 'error.html';
                    }
                });
                return false; // block regular submit
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**My service code book.php**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//Should work in Cross Domaim ajax Calling request
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","2190");
    mysql_select_db("hotels");

    if(isset($_POST['type']))
    {
        if($_POST['type']=="booking"){
            $name = $_POST ['Name'];               
            $mobile = $_POST ['Mob_Num'];
            $mail = $_POST ['Email'];               
            $query1 = "insert into customer(userName, userContactNumber, email) values('$name','$mobile','$mail')";
            $query2 = "insert into booking(cust_name, cust_email, cust_mobile) values('$name', '$mail','$mobile')";         

            $result1=mysql_query($query1);

            $result2=mysql_query($query2);
            echo json_encode($result1);
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid format";
    }
?>
```

Comment: so what's your problem now?

Comment: @CBroe , sorry for that I update please check it..

Comment: @noob, sorry for that I update please check it

Answer (score 1):

U will get it with [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-insert-id.php) after you insert it into the database. it will automatically give you back the latest Auto Increment ID. better one - use PDO or MySQLI because `mysql_insert_id()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_insert_id()` function in PHP to get last inserted ID

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')"); 
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Answer (score 0):

get last inserted id with this and use

```
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql_insert_id() for fetching the inserted id

```
  $result1=mysql_query($query1);
  echo mysql_insert_id()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't echo query result.

use: `mysql_insert_id()` or `mysqli_insert_id()` to return the booking ID.
Note: while using `mysql_insert_id` be careful as it's depreciated in php 5.5 and will be removed in future

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
echo json_encode($id);
```

Then in your ajax success function use php file instead if html and pass this variable:

```
success: function(response){                            
                        window.location.href = "BookingConformation.php?bookingID='+response+'";
                    }
```

Then in your `bookingConfirmation.php` file use get method to fetch this variable:

```
$bookingID=$_GET['bookingID'];
eco $bookinID; //gives your booking id
```

Comment: thanks for reply, In booking table b_id is booking id so how we are returning only writing  $id = mysql_insert_id(); thanks

Comment: if table b_id has auto increment attribute (ie, just increases a number one after other ex: 1,2,3)then mysql_insert_id(); is a sql function which returns the last inserted id

Comment: else if you are using random values to generate booking ID the you have to insert it into the booking table in the using insert statement and pass that value to the success function

Comment: even though if more than 1 person is booking at the same time. Your sql will insert only one row at a time and that row ID will be giving to the inserted customer. SO you need not worry about that part

Comment: sorry I have to asked different question but mistaken asked above question, please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453861/how-to-return-inserted-row-in-mysql-using-json-format