# How to return inserted row in mysql using json format?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have to return the inserted row which is just inserted into json format in the same php code. In this row booking_id is auto generated key, and other information like customer_Name, customer_Email, customer_id. **So How I will return inserted row with additional column booking_id (auto-generated)?.**

**please Note** this question is same as but I forget to asked returning row but asked only returning id. sorry for that. [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453390/how-to-get-the-auto-generated-ids-of-the-row-which-is-inserted-into-table)

**script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#register-form").validate({
            rules: {
                userName: "required",                           
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },                                              
                userContactNumber: "required"                       
            },
            messages: {
                userName: "Please enter your Name",
                userContactNumber: "Please enter your Mobile number",                           
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",                                           
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {

                var uName = $('#userName').val();   
                var mailId = $('#email').val();                 
                var mobNum = $('#userContactNumber').val();

                $.ajax({                
                    url:"http://localhost/bookRoom/book.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{type:"booking", Name:uName, Email:mailId,  Mob_Num:mobNum},                                   
                    ContentType:"application/json",
                    success: function(response){                            
                        window.location.href = 'BookingConformation.html';
                    },
                    error: function(err){                           
                        window.location.href = 'error.html';
                    }
                });
                return false; // block regular submit
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**server code**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//Should work in Cross Domaim ajax Calling request
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","2190");
    mysql_select_db("hotels");

    if(isset($_POST['type']))
    {
        if($_POST['type']=="booking"){
            $name = $_POST ['Name'];               
            $mobile = $_POST ['Mob_Num'];
            $mail = $_POST ['Email'];               
            $query1 = "insert into customer(userName, userContactNumber, email) values('$name','$mobile','$mail')";
            $query2 = "insert into booking(cust_name, cust_email, cust_mobile) values('$name', '$mail','$mobile')";         

            $result1=mysql_query($query1);

            $result2=mysql_query($query2);
            echo json_encode($result1);
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid format";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the id that was auto generated in the insert operation with the [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function

To return it, just create an array with the data you used in the insert and the retrieved id. You can then return the array using json_enode.

Answer (score 0):

use it. i think this is helpful for you

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

use: `mysql_insert_id()` or `mysqli_insert_id()` to return the booking ID.

Note: while using `mysql_insert_id` be careful as it's depreciated in php 5.5 and will be removed in future

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
echo json_encode($id);
```

Then in your ajax `success` function use php file instead of html and pass this booking in a `url query string` and **use this booking ID in your booking.php and write a query to fetch that row**:

```
success: function(response){                            
                        window.location.href = "BookingConformation.php?bookingID='+response+'";
                    }
```

Then in your `bookingConfirmation.php` file use `GET` method to fetch this variable:

```
$bookingID=$_GET['bookingID'];
$query1= "select * from bookin where b_id =".$bookingID;
$result = mysql_query($query1);    
var_dump($result); //gives your array of insterd row
```

Comment: when talking about the future and things you should not be using anymore, consider suggesting not to use mysql_ functions anymore (or mysqli) but using PDO to write prepared statements which help keeping queries secure

Comment: @serjoscha I agree but I was keeping up with the OP format so has to not confuse and deviate from the  problem stated in OP.

Comment: @noob, thanks for reply,  I am not using php code to generate html code, so How I will do that

Comment: @neelabhsingh what the confirmation page should have? (In terms of data) ?

Comment: @ noob, It will have same data like booking_id, customer Name, Mobile email but in html format, I have to assign these value to element define in the conformation.html page..

Comment: @neelabhsingh No you can't. You have to use php file if you want to access the database data!! I fail to understand why you don't want to use php??If you are worrying about data formatting why can't you write html code in php file itself that doesn't make any difference